# Checking if string is in a specific form in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to check if an input string is in this specific form `x,y` because I need these coordinates. I got this as my input-question:

```
x, y = input("Place wall in x,y give q to quit : ").split(",")
```

but how do I check if the user actually gives it in the form `x,y`?

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
p = re.compile("^\d+,\d+$");
while True:
    string = input("Place wall in x,y give q to quit : ")
    if p.match(string):
        break
```

You can then get the values from `string` as before.

Answer (score 1):

Unpacking will throw `ValueError` if your string is not in the right format (does not have comma, has too many commas...) because array after `split()` method will be the wrong size. So you can catch it.

```
try:
    x, y = input("Place wall in x,y give q to quit : ").split(",")
except ValueError:
    print("Unexpected input")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html as a general solution for pattern matching.

You can also just put the data conversions you need to do in a try except block like this

```
try:
    handle_input()
except Exception as e:
    print ("input not correct")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another answer, just because.

```
def check_input(s):
    if s.strip() in ['q', 'Q']:
        raise SystemExit("Goodbye!")

    try:
        x, y = s.split(',')

        # Or whatever specific validation you want here
        if int(x) < 0: raise AssertionError
        if int(y) < 0: raise AssertionError

        return True
    except (ValueError, AssertionError):
        return False

print(check_input("1,3")) # True
print(check_input("foo")) # False
```

Comment: You should not depend on `assert` for input validation. Python does not guarantee that they will run. And when `-O` is given they are not. Use `if x: raise AssertionError` instead if you must.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that.